# Deny specific file extension types in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

In our web application we have an option for the user to upload files. we are validating file extensions on client side and file content on server side. Now we would like to add some filters at IIS level to disallow the specific file extension types. Is it possible to configure some filter at IIS level to deny upload request which has the "*.PDF" as extension? In IIS request filtering module, i have added rule for deny file name extension but there was no luck. When i googled for this problem mostly i found the solutions in the form of code  but not at IIS level. Please advise.

Client Side Code

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
         ID="regValidateFileExtension" runat="server" ControlToValidate="upfile" 
         ErrorMessage="Selected file type not allowed in the system." 
         ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-~ :\\])+(.XLS|.XLSX|.CSV)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Server Side Code:

```
if (fi.Extension.ToUpper() == ".XLS" || fi.Extension.ToUpper() == ".XLSX" || fi.Extension.ToUpper() == ".CSV")
 {
          //call third party dll to check for virus.               
 }
```

When our vendor run security scan they have raised concern over upload functionality. According to initial conversation with them they could intercept the request and send invalid file extensions to the application so we are thinking if we can create some filters at IIS level to stop specific extension or mime types.

Comment: Why must you do it at the IIS level? Why wouldn't you just make this part of your application code?

Comment: It heavily depends on the way you upload the files. In certain ways, IIS only sees raw bytes, and it has no idea what's being sent. That's why Google won't give you specific information. Instead of asking others to guess what you are doing right now, post a complete sample.

Comment: you could use validator in code ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.JPG|.gif|.GIF)$" or if ((extension == ".doc") || (extension == ".xls")){ code } else{"Your file was not uploaded because " + "it does not have a .doc or .xls extension.";} [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I have added more details to description above.